# Add redirect after alert jQuery/ajax/json

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to add a redirect after the alert message once a form is submitted, can anyone help?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: person,
    async:false,
    url: 'https://webapp.example.com/Quote/setleads',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) { 
      if(data.status == 1){
        $('#client_name').val('');
        $('#client_email').val('');
        $('#source').val('');
        $('#datepicker').val('');
        $('#client_telephone').val('');
        $('#lead_note').val('');
        $('#postal_code').val('');
        $("#contact_popup").removeClass("popup_show");
        $("body").css("overflow", "visible")
        alert('Thank you for your request. Someone will 
               get back to you shortly.'); 
      }else if(data.status == 2){
        ...
      }
```

Comment: if you need to redirect to another page, why do you wrote tonns of code to update a current page?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it can help you.

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, removed the first line and add an explanation what the command does